# How to use the data after ajax called success

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

Using Visual Studio 13. How to use the `data` in success function of ajax call? it shows "intellisense was unable to determine an accurate completion list for this expression" every time i select the name after `data.`

When I alert `data` it has no error and works fine, but when alert `data.d` it shows `data.d` is Undefined.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "Service.svc/GetEventTimeSlots",
  data: '{ "eventDate": "' + $("input[id$=hidVisitDate]").val() + '"}',
  //dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  success: function(data) {

    alert(data.d); // message prompt "undefined" 


  }
});
```

I have already added `_references.js` into (intellisense at option), but still it is not working

I need successful result when i use `alert(data.d)`

Comment: learn to use `console` object `alert()` is not a debugging tool

Comment: Is not about the console or alert, is i wan get the value for data.d. There is no problem with the alert.

Comment: Ok, then share the output of `console.log(data)`

Comment: It depends on what you are returning from the `method`. please specify code inside method or What you are  getting in `data`.

Comment: place console.log(data); instead of alert and view the console. you will get the problem

Comment: There is no error when retrieving (data)

{"d":[{"__type":"EventTimeSlotModel:#CRUDObject","AdvanceTicket":20,"AmendedQty":0,"AvailableQtyForSales":36,"AvailableQtyForSalesOnline":16,"Capacity":40,"EventDate":"\/Date(1496160000000+0800)\/","EventTimeSlot":"\/Date(1496192400000+0800)

I just need the value "d":

Comment: change `alert(data.d);` to `alert(data);`

Comment: alert(data) no error,  but i wan the data.d value.

{"d":[{"__type":"EventTimeSlotModel:#CRUDObject","AdvanceTic‌​ket":20,"AmendedQty"‌​:0,"AvailableQtyForS‌​ales":36,"AvailableQ‌​tyForSalesO

Comment: Share your code of this method : GetEventTimeSlots

Answer (score 1):

You dont't need _references.js. 
Your webservice function GetEventTimeSlots is a GET or a POST function? Maybe you have to change the type of your AJAX method.

Comment: i tried, but still does not work.
when i type data."d", there show "!" error, which is something like undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
newdata = JSON.parse(data);
alert(newdata[0].d);
```

you might be missing this `parse`.

Comment: tried this method. still failed. Not sure whether my visual studio need setup anything. Currently using Visual Studio 13

Comment: can you share the screenshot of what you are getting in `alert(data)`? so that we can help you out finding what is the issue.

Comment: The output is something like this

 {"d":[{"__type":"EventTimeSlotModel:#CRUDObject","AdvanceTic‌​ket":20,"AmendedQty"‌​:0,"AvailableQtyForS‌​ales":36,"AvailableQ‌​tyForSalesOnline":16‌​,"Capacity":40,"Even‌​tDate":"\/Date(14961‌​60000000+0800)\/","E‌​ventTimeSlot":"\/Dat‌​e(149619240

Comment: here you need to parse first as i mentioned above and then you have to get data as `data[0].d` this will give you data as you want. I've updated my answer acoordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to parse the JSON data.

```
    var parsed_data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    alert(parsed_data.d);
```